# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: web-part

```
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPListCollection docLibraryColl = oWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.GenericList);

                foreach (SPList list in docLibraryColl)
                {
                    if (list.Title == "Uygulamalar")
                    {
                        SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
                        oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignTo'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>";
                        SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(oQuery);

                        foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
                        {
                            item.Delete();
                        }

                        foreach (string item in apps)
                        {
                            CheckBox cb = this.FindControl("cb" + item) as CheckBox;
                            if (cb.Checked)
                            {
                                SPListItem oSPListItem = list.Items.Add();
                                oSPListItem["Title"] = item;
                                oSPListItem["AssignTo"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID;
                                oSPListItem.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is why you're getting that message. I think it's because you're deleting an item within an enumeration - collListItems - which modifies the enumeration to that it can't, um, enumerate.

Instead, build a list of the things you want to delete, and then work through that:

```
List<SPListItem> toDelete = new List<SPListItem>();
foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
{
    toDelete.Add(item);
}
foreach(SPListItem deleteMe in toDelete) 
{
    deleteMe.Delete();
}
```

Yes, it does seem long winded.

Comment: I did use that but still getting same error :/ didn't take from one collection to another. simply nothing changed but collections name?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems.ToArray())
{
    item.Delete();
}
```

Or use a for loop instead.